# boost signals: Expose signal itself or connect / disconnect methods in class interface?

Tags: c++, boost, signals-slots, boost-signals2

When having signals in a class, is it considered being good practice to expose the signal itself in the class "interface"?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    boost::signals2::signal<void()>& SomethingHappened()
    {
        return m_Signal;
    }

private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> m_Signal;
};
```

I've seen people writing "register" (and possibly "unregister") functions instead:

```
class MyClass2
{
public:
    boost::signals2::connection RegisterHandler(std::function<void()>& handler)
    {
        return m_Signal.connect(handler);
    }

private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> m_Signal;
};
```

I'd prefer the 1st approach because I don't want to limit the users of my class to the functions I offer. However, is there a good reason to prefer the 2nd approach?

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd variant is not so good: you don't allow the caller to use signal's tracking mechanism.

But if you'd substitute `function` with `your_signal::slot_type` (or event better, `your_signal::extended_slot_type`), it would provide better encapsulation than the 1st variant. In particular, it would prevent callers from misusing (or abusing) `m_Signal`, like this:

```
SomethingHappened().disconnect_all();
```

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. This way the caller can start tracking when connecting instead of explicitly disconnecting.